# stream a file to a vector<float> with copy+back_inserter

Tags: c++, vector, stream, ifstream

I need to read floats out of a file and push them into my vector. I can get his to work by using a temp float but I'm trying without one now.

For some reason the following doesn't work.

```
std::ifstream fileHandle(filename);
std::vector<float> vect;
std::string id;
while (!fileHandle.eof()){
    fileHandle >> id;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<float>(fileHandle),
              std::istream_iterator<float>(),
              std::back_inserter(vect));
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<float>(fileHandle),
              std::istream_iterator<float>(),
              std::back_inserter(vect));
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<float>(fileHandle),
              std::istream_iterator<float>(),
              std::back_inserter(vect));
}
```

with a file looking like

```
v 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
...
```

Debugging it, it seems the first `copy` call pushes **3** floats (the whole line) into the vector. This would actually be fine except it also seems to freeze my file iterator at the next line's 'v'. The `fileHandle >> id;` line and the `copy` calls don't move the file iterator forward from that point on, creating an infinite loop. Using only 1 `copy` call created the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>

// it is a good idea to create an structure to hold the data you will
// be working with. In this case I am creating a bare-bones struct
// containing a single data element
struct entry {
  double data[3];  
};

// when you have an structure, you can overload the >> operator; this
// will allow you to simplify later calls (as you will see below). In
// this case, because your data file contains a "dummy" character I
// use a dummy string. Notice that the return type is bool, and it
// means "I was able to read what you wanted me to read", in this case
// a line with one string and three doubles (because the type of each
// e.data[k] is "double")
bool operator>>(std::istream& is, entry& e) {
  std::string dummy;
  return is>>dummy>>e.data[0]>>e.data[1]>>e.data[2];
}


int main() {
  // create a vector to hold the entries (notice that "entry" is the
  // data type you created above)
  std::vector<entry> entries;

  { // the bracket on the left will provide a "scope" for the "fp"
    // variable. When the scope ends, "fp" will be automatically
    // destroyed. For "fp" that means that the "close()" method will
    // be called upon destruction, and you don't need to worry about
    // ensuring that your files are closed (to lear more about this
    // google for RAII)

    std::ifstream fp("test.txt");
    // the iterators DO NOT REQUIRE A LOOP (they "provide" the loop;
    // they are used precisely to avoid coding the loop)

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<entry>(fp),
              std::istream_iterator<entry>(),
              std::back_inserter<std::vector<entry>>(entries));
    // notice that the back inserter will insert "entry" types into
    // the "entries" vector as long as it can continue reading them
    // (that is, as long as ">>" continues to return "true"

  } // the bracket on the left is finishing the scope I talked about
    // above. Past this point fp no longer exists, and the file has
    // been closed

  // off you go - you have your vector full of "entry" instances which
  // you can use normally
  std::cout<<"read "<<entries.size()<<" entries: "<<std::endl;
  for(auto e:entries) {
    std::cout<<e.data[0]<<", "<<e.data[1]<<", "<<e.data[2]<<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled this source code using gcc 4.7.2 using:

```
g++ example.cpp -std=c++11
```

With the file exactly as you provided it (I called it "test.txt") I get the following:

```
read 2 entries: 
0, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the comments are quite useful. I'm actually using the dummy char as an identifier that goes through a switch statement but I think I can figure out how to make the appropriate changes.

Comment: You can augment the "struct" with the desired behavior, and put all the logic in the "operator>>" - you first read "dummy" (which you can call "flag", or something not as dummy), and "mark" each entry accordingly.

Comment: The lines are different based on the identifier (not always floats and not always 3). They are in order though (v lines come before n lines, etc). So I think I'll make a struct for each type of line and overload the `<<` so that it returns false with the wrong identifier. That make sense?

Comment: Probably not, because you will have to "keep state" in your file pointer. It is better if you post the whole problem and we can try to help you solve it. If an "entry" can have different things, it is best to create a class that fully represents it (for every possible case), and let >> do its work (which is "read ALL the entries", as opposed to "read a few entries")

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple approach using Boost Spirit.

This lends you incredible flexibility because it defines an actual grammar inline:

```
('v' >> qi::float_ >> qi::float_ >> qi::float_) % qi::eol,
```

Here's the full program:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::cin >> std::noskipws;
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(std::cin), l;

    std::vector<float> vect;

    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l, // std::cin
            ('v' >> qi::float_ >> qi::float_ >> qi::float_) % qi::eol,
            qi::blank, // ignore any whitespace separators
            vect);     // keep appending to a vector 
            // (this could easily be a vector of structs containing 3 floats)

    if (ok)   
    {
        std::cout << "parse success\n";

        // only for verification output:
        using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
        std::cout << "parsed vect: \n" << format_delimited(columns(3) [ *auto_ ], ' ', vect) << "\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    return ok;
}
```